# What are the androidx.XXXX.version files in META-INF of my APK?

Tags: android, androidx

When an APK is built with AndroidX libraries, I get a lot of small text files like `META-INF/androidx.core_core.version`. What is the purpose of these files? How are they used by **androidx**?

Answer (score 4):

I was recently curious as well, so I browsed the source code a bit.

The first attempt for version information injection was [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/310f81dc46e0f0531a136e50314bc0352e56ac60); it was implemented by adding a meta-data tag into AndroidManifest.xml.

Then came a pair ([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/72bb9952e7db82279af7bd4cc770a619947d39f3), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/c7c49c6dded4941a4184d7fedfc3c4f2942bf612)) of commits which added a task (into Gradle plugin, that is shared between many/all? androidx libraries), whose sole purpose is to generate the *.version files. This approach replaced the earlier meta-data tag injection, where the reason is (from commit message):

> Previously support library tracked its usage by adding meta-data tags
> to each library, however that caused issues for certain libraries as
> there is a high cost associated with services and meta-data in package
> manager.
>
> To work around this issue move to storing version information in java
> resource inside the jar META-INF/group_name.version.

However, that doesn't answer the question - as none of these commits mention the reasoning behind storing the version information in androidx libraries.
I've also tried to [search for *.version usages](https://cs.android.com/search?q=%5C.version%5C%22&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport) in the androidx codebase, but unfortunately couldn't find anything interesting.

Eventually, the author of *.version generation task [was kind enough to shed some light](https://twitter.com/_aurimas/status/1551236667746373632) on their purpose:

> The main purpose for them is for us to be able to track which versions
> of androidx libraries are being used by the apps in the play store or
> when someone submits a failing repro APK. We also recently started
> using in compose inspection tool on studio side to detect what
> features should be available given the library version.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. They cannot use code inspection in Play Store because proguard.

Comment: Are these files safe to exclude from the final release APK?